# Structured data error "Missing: author" and "Missing: updated" in search console

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data

In search console, it is showing following errors:

> Missing: author
>   Missing: updated

Errors are shown for 2 pages: "about us" and "disclaimer" page.

I'm using "all in one schema.org rich snippets" plugin in WordPress. 
But for these 2 pages, I didn't select the rich data option.

And when i'm validating the page in Google structured data validator, then is showing 0 errors and 0 warning.

What is the problem and jow to correct them?